# JSP file not rendered in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot web application that reads index.jsp and uses tomcat jasper to support JSP. However, the page is showing up as "There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)." I suspect either the issue lies with the dependency.

pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.Alex</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WebApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.35</version>
</dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

index.jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello this shit works
</body>
</html>
```

The method runs as the print statement executes

```
@Controller
public class indexController {

// Tomcat Jasper to return jsp files
@RequestMapping("index")
public String getIndex() {
    System.out.println("test1");
    return "index.jsp";
}
```

File structure

[image]

Comment: Should you config ViewResolver ? and where is you jsp file?

Comment: Yeah I used it for Spring MVC but from the tutorial I'm going through it says use Jasper to resolve the JSP. JSP : src\main\views\index.jsp

Comment: I think that the main/webapp is suitable where jsp files are

Comment: @rezaramezanimatin that didn't resolve the problem, my best guess is the problem is with the dependencies comparability

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency with other  ( like web ) in your **pom** file.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

In **application.properties** file add this config properties for file location (**Your .jsp file location in class path**)

**Properties** config:

```
        spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/views/
        spring.mvc.view.suffix =.jsp
        spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

OR

**Class level** config:

```
        @Configuration
        @EnableWebMvc
        @ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.imran"})
        public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

            public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
                registry.jsp().prefix("/WEB-INF/views/").suffix(".jsp");
            }
            public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
            }


        }
```

and your controller will be like this (**with out .jsp extension, just file name**):

```
        @Controller
        public class indexController  {
            
            @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public String getIndex() {
                System.out.println("test1");
                return "index";
            }

        }
```

You can get some help from [here](https://github.com/imrangthub/SpBootBlogSolutionUsingWithJdbc) if you need.

Comment: I've tried your solution but I'm getting the same result. Regarding the dependency, I'm using STS 4 and I checked they are already added  in the project somewhere ( not sure where but search results shows it pops up ). Do I still have to add it to the maven dependencies?

Comment: You must add this dependency on your pom file because an Application build with those dependencies what is in it's pom file.
Some time property configuration not working for several cos, I add class level configuration you can try with this.

Comment: And file JSP file/folder location must be correct on the config file.

Comment: Yeah I use  spring.mvc.view.prefix = /main/views/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring starter project then that won't find the path
you have to create new project as "dynamic web project" then
you will get the folder web-inf and inside you can create views and the set path in properties file ...
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix =.jsp